# How to cancel Service/IntentService/AsyncTask/Looper

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, looper, intentservice

I'm going nuts here.
I want a simple thing - I have a long task (fetching several data objects from the web) and I want the ability to cancel it.
I tried a lot of things (a lot) and nothing works

The flow goes like this:

1. the user click on a button
2. I start the work (I tried with `AsyncTask`, `Service`, `IntentService` and `Looper`)
3. the task takes care of everything including adding ongoing notification for progress updates
4. the intent in the notification has a call for a new activity that her only purpose is to cancel the ongoing task
5. in the cancelActivity I tried to call `stopService()` for Service/IntentService or do 
   `Looper.quit()` for the Looper (I don't remember what I tried for AsyncTask, not sure if there is such api for canceling it)

In my point of view the best option will be using `IntentService` (I could have several task lining up and IntetService will do it in order like I want) but
I'm open to suggestions for any type of implementation - I don't care what the code will be, just that I will have the option to cancel the task

Thank you in advance for your help

Dror

(I'm off to bed - 8 hours on the same issue is just too much)

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter what specific operation you use to stop the task if you don't recognize the stop condition in your background logic. The only way to cleanly accomplish it is if background worker stops and exits  in good faith.

There are few possible scenarios and solutions that you can use for canceling background work.

- Background thread executes many short steps (for example computation with some loops). In this case, check some flag (could be `isInterrupted()`) between operations and exit if this flag indicates that operation must stop.
- Background thread is waiting on monitor. Call `interrupt()` on background thread, catch exception in in exception handler make appropriate steps to finish this task cleanly and exit.
- Background thread is waiting on IO. This use case is very hard to solve in general case. If you use some socket, you can try closing this socket externally and catch the exception. In worst case scenario, you can just abandon the thread in the state that if it ever returns from IO it knows that it is canceled and IO results must be discarded. If you do it often - you will run out of memory, so I would not really recommend it.

In any case, there is no way (except killing the thread which is really bad) to stop your task if it does not know about possibility of being stopped.

Comment: thank you for the replay. Using interrupt() is not working due to the fact that my task is already working (connecting to the web site) so it won't stop it. I will be able to stop only the next objects to be executed by using `isIterrupted()`. I'm not directly opening the socket (I use Jsoup `connect()` library to get html web page to parse it). How can I close it?

Comment: from your own answer it follows that you are waiting on the socket (or doing some other networking stuff), so interrupt is not going to work. Shutting down connection manager has effect of terminating network communications that is closing sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i manged to do something close to what I want.

I'm using IntentService that will queue my task. each new task is `AsyncTask`. the AsyncTask starts with sending notification with pendingIntent for cancelActivity.

When clicking on the notification the user gets a warning popup about stopping the task. If he clicks yes than I do `stopService()` on my IntentService.

In the IntentService I added:

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    currentTask.cancel(true);
    if (mNotificationHelper != null)
        mNotificationHelper.completed();
    super.onDestroy();
    stopSelf();
}
```

in the AsyncTask I added:

```
    @Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    isCanclled = true;
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    mNotificationHelper.completed();
    if (mAsyncTaskListener != null)
        mAsyncTaskListener.AsyncTaskCanceled();
}
```

so that will drop all the connection currently in motion. In the actual code that do the work I need to catch the exception for connection shutdown and handle it

so in the end I'm not actually stopping the AsyncTask/Service but rather exposing the `httpClient` so I will be able to drop the connection in asynchrony why.

I think is a bit ugly but I got no other way

thank you all